# super props inheritance not working

Tags: reactjs

It seems that the props in App doesn't inherit the props of the base component. because whenever I log the value of props in the console. it's like this.
Any thoughts what my problem is? Thank you
[image]

```
    class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            count: 1
        }
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="6" md-offset="3">
                        <LogRegContainer name={"hello"}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not enough information to answer. What do you see in the console, when you render `App` like the following: `<App testProp={true} />`?

Comment: Object
testProp: true
__proto__: Object.

it shows this. sorry im new, thanks

Comment: Yes, that means that you got prop from the parent correctly. What do you want to receive instead?

Comment: i want to use the context to change routes.

Comment: You need to show us where it's rendered for us to understand further. i.e., `<App {/** props will be listed here */} />`

Comment: Thank you guys for responding. I solved it already. it seems that i need to define routes first. so i can see the router , locations, route properties. etc.